# Trouble understanding output from RegEx boolean

Tags: ruby, regex, boolean, eval

I'm supposed to test if 'name' is consisting of letters:

```
name = "Jack"

test = 'name =~ /^[A-Z]/'
```

As far as i understand, this:

```
puts eval(test)
```

should return: TRUE, but the output given is a '0', (yes, i know that 0 in some languages == false..)

But if i try the eval in an if-statement..

```
if eval(test)
puts 'yeah'
end
```

..i get the expected outcome.. TRUE, or rather: 'yeah'..

Why cant i get the 'correct' output right away? Have'nt found anything that makes sense, from my friends @ Google..

Comment: Your regex does not check if the string consists of letters. It checks if it starts with a capital letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=~` returns the position of match.

In ruby everything except `nil` and `false` is considered true. Even `0` is true!

One way to convert anything to bool is to use `!!`.

Comment: So, what i'm actually getting is the first position that matches A-Z? Thanks.

Comment: Are regexes case insensitive by default in Ruby? Interesting.

Comment: @Mr Lister: they are case sensitive. check again, `^` is not in `[]` ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get true/false values, you can write

```
!!(name =~ /^[A-Z]/)
```

but it is not necessary, since `if` works well with the value returned by `=~`

Comment: Further on i'm 'testing' a lot more expressions, of different types. !! works for all of them, thanks!